# How to group string values from a specific column and creating and additional column with the grouped strings?

Tags: google-bigquery, bigquery-udf

I have the following schema:

View
Campaign ,
Date,
Source___medium,
Keyword,
Sessions,
New_sessions__,
Avg__session_length__sec_,
Users,
New_users,
Bounces,
Goal_completions_all_goals

And I would like to group Source/Medium string names items in specific groups:

For example in source and medium I have fields like google/Organic , google/discovery , google/ CPC , Paid  /search , Facebook / social and I would like to group them as Google Organic , Video Discovery, Google CPC, Paid Search, Facebook Organic etc. How can I do this?

And then when I have created the grouping column how i will be able to add this column to the original one?

Answer (score 1):

> how i will be able to add this column to the original one?

Consider using below UDF and also see example of use

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION DECODE(expr ANY TYPE, map ANY TYPE, `default` ANY TYPE ) AS ((
  IFNULL((SELECT result FROM UNNEST(map)  WHERE lower(search) = lower(expr)), `default`)
));  
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
    select 'google/Organic' Source_medium union all
    select 'google/discovery' union all
    select 'google/ CPC' union all
    select 'Paid /search' union all
    select 'Facebook / social' 
)
SELECT Source_medium,
  DECODE(Source_medium, 
    [STRUCT<search STRING, result STRING>
    ('google/Organic', 'Google Organic'),
    ('google/discovery', 'Video Discovery'),
    ('google/ CPC', 'Google CPC'),
    ('Paid /search', 'Paid Search'),
    ('Facebook / social', 'Facebook Organic')
    ], 'Other') AS Adjusted_Source_medium
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

Output for above example is

[image]

Comment: Hi Thank you for your help. However, how can i group source_medium fields that have different variability. For instance if i would like to group, strings that contains google or Google and Organic or Ogranic into Google Organic how can I reformulate the function?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do the following

Alter the table to allow for the additional column

```
ALTER TABLE mydataset.mytable
      ADD COLUMN grouped_column STRING;
```

Create a function to handle the logic

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION grouper (source_medium string)
AS (
    CASE source_medium
    WHEN 'google/Organic' THEN 'Google Organic'
    ELSE 'OTHER LOGIC' END
);
```

Update the table using the function you created

```
UPDATE mydataset.mytable
set grouped_column = grouper(Source___medium)
where true
```

Alternatively you could do this with a view sitting on top of your underlying table as follows:

```
CREATE VIEW  mydataset.myview AS
SELECT *
   , CASE source___medium
     WHEN 'google/Organic' THEN 'Google Organic'
     ELSE 'OTHER LOGIC' END
FROM mydataset.mytable
```